# nginx rewrite rules to IIS7 rules?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config, rules

I am trying to convert nginx rewrite rule to web.config on IIS7.

nginx:

```
    location /api {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$request_uri;
}
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

so far i only managed to convert first bit, but I have no clue how to do the second bit. It kind of works but  I don't know what's the last rule for

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="api" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
     ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
      ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="api/index.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="/*" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
        ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
        ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last rule is for PHP fast CGI setting with Nginx.

In iis you could configure PHP fast CGI by below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

if you don't want to manually configure this thing you could directly enable iis CGI feature.

[image]

Download web platform installer.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

- At the top of the Web Platform Installer window, click Products.
- Click Frameworks, and then select the current version of PHP.
- Click Install. The Web Platform Installation page displays the version of PHP and its dependencies that will be installed.
- Click I Accept. Web PI installs the PHP packages.
- Click Finish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php